# Android Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager in my activity. Inside the viewpager, there is a fragment and the fragment contains recyclerview. Once a notification is received, I want to add the new item in my recyclerview and want to highlight it as well.

Activity class:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    boolean not_id = intent.getBooleanExtra(AppConstants.NEW_NOTIFICATION, false);
    String bid_id = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.BID_NOTIFICATION_ID);
    if(not_id){
        ActiveBidFragment frag = ActiveBidFragment.newInstance(bid_id, "");
        frag.setBid_id(bid_id);
        frag.newBidReceived();
        frag.setBid_id("0");
        Log.i(TAG,"~~~~done refreshing");
    }

}
```

Fragment:

```
    public void newBidReceived(){
        fetchActiveBids();
    }
private void fetchActiveBids(){
        if(mActiveBidPresenter == null)
            mActiveBidPresenter = new ActiveBidPresenterImpl(this);
        mActiveBidPresenter.getActiveBids();
    }
@Override
public void onFetchedActiceBidsSuccess() {
    if(bids == null)
        bids = new ArrayList<ActiveBid>();
    bids.clear();
    bids.addAll(AppContext.getInstance().getActiveBids());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Adapter class:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "~~~~on Bind Holder");
        String bid_id = ((ActiveBidFragment) mListener).getCurrentBidId();
        List<Bid> bids = mActiveBids.get(position).getBid();
```

The presenter class calls a method to show dialog,which is:

Presenter Class:

```
 @Override
    public void getActiveBids() {
        mActiveBidView.showProgressBar(AppConstants.FETCHING_ACTIVE_BIDS);
        String vendor_id = Preferences.getActiveInstance(null).getVendor_id();
        mActiveBidInteractor.fetchActiveBids(vendor_id, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void showProgressBar(String msg) {
        if(mProgressBar != null && mProgressBar.isShowing())
            mProgressBar.dismiss();
        mProgressBar = CodeUtil.generateWaitingDialog(getActivity(), msg);
        mProgressBar.show();
    }
@Override
    public void fetchedActiveBidSuccessfully(JSONObject response) {
        try{
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ActiveBidResponse resp = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ActiveBidResponse.class);
            String status = resp.getStatus();
            if(status.equals(AppConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                List<ActiveBid> activeBids = resp.getData();
                AppContext.getInstance().setActiveBids(activeBids);
                //AppContext.getInstance().setFetchNewActiveBids(false);
                mActiveBidView.onFetchedActiceBidsSuccess();
            }else{
                mActiveBidView.onFetchedActiveBidsFailed();
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            mActiveBidView.onFetchedActiveBidsFailed();
        }
        finally {
            mActiveBidView.hideProgressBar();
        }
    }
```

Interactor Class:

```
@Override
    public void fetchActiveBids(String vendor_id, OnActiveBidFinished mListener) {
        String url = AppConstants.ACTIVE_BID_URL;
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(AppConstants.VENDOR_ID, vendor_id);

        JsonObjectRequest loginRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new JSONObject(params),
                createMyReqSuccessListener(mListener),
                createMyReqErrorListener(mListener));

        VolleySingleton.getRequestQueue().add(loginRequest);
    }
```

Dialog Class:

```
public static ProgressDialog generateWaitingDialog(Context context, String message){
        ProgressDialog  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);
        return progressDialog;
    }
```

In dialog, I get error as a nullpointerexception, it shows getActivity as null.
Is there some other way I can achieve what I am trying to achieve, may be like recreating the whole instance of the activity if the activity already exists

Update:
Changed the fragment creation to this:

```
 ActiveBidFragment frag =  (ActiveBidFragment) adapter.getItem(0);
                    frag.setBid_id(bid_id);
                    frag.newBidReceived();
                    frag.setBid_id("0");

//adapter is the viewpagerpadapter to which fragment is attached
```

Comment: In your onNewIntent function, the new fragment you are creating is declare locally and will be destroyed as soon as you leave those curly braces, i.e. straight after the log line, as the fragment is only scoped within those braces.

Comment: So how to get the current fragment instance inside parent activity. P.S.: My layout file does not contain any fragment tag.  Or how can I achieve what I am trying to achieve.  BTW, the showProgressBar is called inside that loop only

Comment: when and where showProgressBar is called?

Comment: added the whole code

Comment: What is the exact error message and line of code which causes it?

Comment: is creating a new fragment instance creating a problem. Should I make the fragment singleton, although its a bad coding practice, I guess

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference                                                                                                          Its on line ProgressDialog  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am maintaining the fragment instance in a hashmap inside my fragmentpageradapter and then I am referncing it in my onNewIntent. That's the only solution I could get. Its like a singleton pattern, till the activity is alive. If someone postes better solution, I would seriously like to know it

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment will get the `getActivity()` always null, unless your fragment is attached with the activity.

In your case:

```
ActiveBidFragment frag = ActiveBidFragment.newInstance(bid_id, "");
frag.setBid_id(bid_id);
frag.newBidReceived();
```

frag is not attach with any activity.

Comment: Yeah I know, new instance of the fragment is causing the problem, I have already mentioned in the comments. How do I solve this, should I make fragment singleton?

Comment: @mayank I don't think it is a good practise, I suggest you can wait to call getActivity()/newBidReceived() stuff in your fragment's onCreate() function implement.

Comment: Modified the code for fragment instantiation, still getting same error. Can you have a look at that